# How to implement a (low priority) scheduled workstealing ExecutorService?

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice, thread-priority, work-stealing

My project requires two low priority tasks to be done regularly. Simple solution is to have a scheduled executor with the two tasks scheduled at fixed rate.

Now the problem is: there might be other tasks of higher priority. The obvious solution might be to go with workStealingPools. Though I can't find implementations of scheduled workstealing pools.

Is there a better/different approach for this, or is there a logical reason why this doesn't make sense? Or: how to implement such a solution?

Comment: can't you create a queue that has a `Comparator` based on that priority? PriorityBlockingQueue for example?

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-multi-threading/fork-and-join/

Comment: Both are already to "powerful" for the low-key application I have in mind. Thus seems as if the choice is between just ignoring possible inefficiencies, and going overkill. But thank you anyway.